# angular $compile not working when adding a new directive

Tags: angularjs

```
    (function(){

        angular
            .module('main')
            .directive('search', search);

        search.$inject = ['$compile'];

        function search($compile){

            return {
                link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
                    ele.bind('click', function(){
                        var template = "<search-results>{{searchCtrl.results.length}}</search-results>";
                        $compile(template)(scope);
                        $('.resultsContainer').append(template);
                    });
                }
            }

        }

    })();
```

`<search-results></search-results>` is another directive, which is below:

```
(function(){

    angular
        .module('main')
        .directive('searchResults', searchResults);

    searchResults.$inject = [];

    function searchResults(){

        return {
            templateUrl: 'main/views/resultsContainer.client.view.html',
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
                ele.bind('click', function(){

                });
            }
        }

    }

})();
```

The directive which i am trying to add at the beginning () did not get compiled and i got this

```
<search-results>{{searchCtrl.results.length}}</search-results>
```

as output. scope values are not inject into it. But the new directive added itself has another template to be pulled, which is done. i saw the request to the template in console.

Can someone find my mistake

Comment: try `template = $compile(template)(scope);` ... you need to append the results of the compile

Comment: Hey hey.. It worked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the results returned by `$compile` to be appended

Try changing:

```
 $compile(template)(scope);
```

To

```
template = $compile(template)(scope);
```